# Why does twitter bootstrap.js use the $.Event object in jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap

For the [modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) [code](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js) inside the twitter bootstrap.js plugin, I see this:

```
e = $.Event('show')
this.$element.trigger(e)
```

Why don't they just do `$.element.show()`?

Why is the [jQuery Event constructor](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) being used?

Here is the show method from the source:

```
show: function () {
   var that = this
      , e = $.Event('show')

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    $('body').addClass('modal-open')

    this.isShown = true

    escape.call(this)
    backdrop.call(this, function () {
      var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

      if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
        that.$element.appendTo(document.body) //don't move modals dom position
      }

      that.$element.show()

      if (transition) {
         that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      }

      that.$element.addClass('in')

      transition ?
        that.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () { that.$element.trigger('shown') }) :
        that.$element.trigger('shown')

    })
  }
```

Could someone explain this to me clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Because it's giving us the opportunity to react to the event.

thanks to this, if you want react when modal its going to open you only should add an event listener:

```js
$("#myModal").on("show", function () {
    console.log("Do stuff on 'show'");
});
```

Just to be clear. they created an event called "show" but can be any name since its used only for that plugin. Even if they had called "showme-the-money" you shoud  only listen that event:

```js
$("#myModal").on("showme-the-money", function () {
    console.log("Sorry i'm poor :(");
});
```

Comment: But why they don't just use `this.$element.trigger('show');` as it is done with the event `shown` at the end of the posted script?